# ADB can't list my device (Sony Xperia S)

Tags: android

I found that I cannot update my device to the ADB connectable driver, what's wrong with that???

When I updated my device to the adb connectable driver (..sdk\extras\google\usb_driver),
and then press 'Next, it shows
'Window has determined the driver software for your device is up to date. 
WPD Composite Device'

I have already spent many hours to the solve,please help me.

Comment: Download and install the official driver from their website. Turn on Debugging on your phone.

Comment: I have turned on the debugging on my phone, and downloaded the official driver from Sony(http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-s-xperia-nx-and-xperia-acro-hd-drivers/), when I install it, it gave me the same answer "Window has determined the driver software for your device is up to date. WPD Composite Device'"

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with my xperia u, and I use [this](http://androidxda.com/download-sony-xperia-usb-driver) page to download driver. After intalling driver, adb works with device like a charm.

Comment: the same as I mentioned. "it shows 'Window has determined the driver software for your device is up to date. WPD Composite Device'"... :(

Comment: when intalling driver, try choose "Let me pick from a list of device driver.." -> "Have disk" and then specify unpacked .inf file.

Comment: when I did it, and selected the .inf file, it shows "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software drive for you device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems."

Comment: I got my driver here: http://www.droidjar.com/download-sony-xperia-adb-usb-drivers/ for a Sony Xperia S - unzipped and installed on a 32-Bit Windows 7 - works fine and the device is now being recognized in Android Studio. Important: When pointing the device manager to the folder I had to select the top-level folder, not the i386 folder!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server` and replug the device.

Also, find the `adb_usb.ini` file (usually in your home folder) and add a line with `054c` (Extracted from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)).

Comment: Ok, you should not "-1" the answer if it doesn't work for you, for others it can be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Also, try the @Doornsknight solution, try to download the official drivers from the Sony website). Some people had to reinstall the drivers to get it working